Teflon tube end plugs came out of Creality V3 Plus
I just assembled a Creality 3D Printer Ender-3 V3 Plus. The teflon tube end plugs came out at both ends. How do I get them back in?


https://www.google.com/search?q=ender+3+bowden+tube+replacement
